# Is it possible to have different route files in Express (NodeJS) app?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, directory, passport.js

I'm a `NodeJS` beginner and I'm using `express`. My directory is like this :

```
    __app
    |_assets
    |_controllers
        |_somemodel.controller.js

    |_models 
        |_somemodel.model.js
        |_user.model.js

    |_routes
        |_route.js
        |_passport.routes.js 
        |_somemodel.routes.js

    |_views
        |_note 
            |_index.ejs

        |_passport
            |_index.ejs
            |_login.ejs
            |_profile.ejs
            ...

__config
    |_database.config.js
    |_passport.config.js

__node_modules

package.json
server.js
```

the thing I wanna know is that is it possible to have a general routes file and then include or require other route files in that ? Like my `route.js` ?
And is this directory correct while using `Express` and `Passport` as authentication?

Comment: Have a file which sole purpose is to create `const app = express()` and exports it. In the route definition files import this module. Then in the "main" file do the other required configuration steps (and import the route definitions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can require other route files into a common file like bellow.

**somemodel.contoller.js**

```
module.exports.someMethod = (req, res) => {
  // do something
}
```

**somemodel.routes.js**

```
const controller = require("path-to-somemodel-controller")

module.exports = (app) {
  app.route("/somepath")
    .get(controller.someMethod)
     // other methods
}
```

**route.js**

```
 // you need to parse the app into route module
  module.exports = (app) => {
    require('somemodel.routes')(app);
    // others goes here
  }
```

**server.js**

```
const app = express();
require('path-to-route.js')(app
```

)